# Is any problem with my computer or my commands when installing openpose?

Tags: gcc, cmake, g++, ubuntu-18.04, openpose

I have big trouble installing openpose from git repository.
I'm kinda beginner so I think problem is from me.

Github repository :
    https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose

My system

```
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

cmake 3.14.5

caffe 1.0.0

opencv : seems 2 versions are installed : 4.0.1-dev and 3.2.0.
```

I don't know if I can switch versions when installing openpose. when I run python3, then

```
import cv2

cv2.__version__
```

gives 4.0.1-dev

gcc 7.4.0

cudnn 7.1.2

cuda 9.1.85

gpu is Nvidia GP102 [titan X]

I'trying to follow installation instructions :
    https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation.md#installation

I had trouble using cmake GUI so insted I ran the following commands :

```
$ cmake -DCaffe_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include -DCaffe_LIBS=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaffe.so -DBUILD_CAFE=OFF ..

$ cmake -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 -DCUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 -DCUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda-8.0
```

then cmake told that that was correct.

Maybe installation wasn't correct since these steps.

Then step openpose building : I ran following commands :

```
$ cd build/

$ make -j`nproc`
```

got many errors like that :

```
    In file included from /usr/include/host_config.h:50:0,
                 from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:78,
                 from <command-line>:0:
    /usr/include/crt/host_config.h:121:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 6 are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 6 are not supported!
```

gcc version is 7.4.0 so I ran make command again specifying older gcc versions, according to gcc versions installed :

```
$ make CC=gcc-6 CPP=g++-6 CXX=g++-6 LD=g++-6 -j`nproc`
```

then :

```
$ make CC=gcc-4.8 CPP=g++-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 LD=g++-4.6 -j`nproc`
```

but got the same errors again.

Comment: This is likely unrelated to the error you're seeing, but your second `cmake` call is missing the `-D` on the definition: `-DCUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda-8.0`

Comment: So the command must be : cmake -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 -DCUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 -DCUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 -DCUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda-8.0  I tried and got this : CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


CMake Error: The source directory "/home/morgane_eos" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Since you are deviating from the provided instructions on Github, I suggest you familiarize yourself with how to run CMake, and using the CMake command line ([here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html)).

Comment: @squareskittles I ended going on a rush.
First I followed provided instructions, got some errors while starting CMake-gui, googled these errors and forgot these, then applyied answers to error messages similar to mine.
Caffe was already installed.
Computer's busy now, when it will be available I'm going to see if I can perform installation following provided instructions - if possible.
Thank you for your helps

Comment: When opening cmake, then pressing configure I have the following message :
Caffe will be built from source now.
Download the models.
Downloading BODY_25 model...
Model already exists.
Not downloading body (COCO) model
Not downloading body (MPI) model
Downloading face model...
Model already exists.
Downloading hand model...
Model already exists.
Models Downloaded.
Configuring done

Then when pressing Generate, generating is immediate and I've the message "Generation done"

Comment: It sounds like CMake completed successfully, so now you want to run `make` to compile the code.

Comment: @squareskittles  yes, exactly. I can't run make, always tells me gcc versions later than 6 are not supported, even if I try to specify older versions